# Google maps offline

Tags: google-maps

Cannot find menu: how to make google map available offline. I googled and [found](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/2650377) but dont have menu `make available offline` in settings.

Comment: What version of Google apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type 'ok map' in search box and press enter.

Comment: They really need to put the interface for offline maps back in. This way is easy enough once you know how but impossible for a new user to figure out without reading the "Tips & Tricks" section in the menu.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Would you mind to [edit] your answer and add a few more details what to expect? AFAIK the offline capabilities have been restricted a lot with recent versions (I do not use GMaps, so I cannot tell from my own experience).

Comment: The interface IS available, as I describe in my answer.  They've just made a mess of the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Starting on November 10, 2015, Google Maps will roll out a new offline mode for Android allowing for driving directions and search. It's designed to fit seamlessly alongside the online version of Google Maps, allowing data connection to drop in and out without interrupting the app itself.

From the [Official Google Blog: Navigate and search the real world … online or off](https://googleblog.blogspot.co.il/2015/11/navigate-and-search-real-world-online.html):

> You can download an area by searching for a city, county or country, for instance, and tapping *Download* on the resulting place sheet, or by going to *Offline Areas* in the Google Maps menu and tapping on the +</> button. Once downloaded, Google Maps will move into offline mode automatically when it recognizes you're in a location with spotty service or no connectivity at all. When a connection is found, it will switch back online so you can easily access the full version of Maps, including live traffic conditions for your current route. By default, Google Maps will only download areas to your device when you are on a Wi-Fi connection to prevent large data fees.

[image: Screenshot]
       <sup>(Click image to see animation)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

That help doesn't work for me, but it's not for the same version I'm using, which is v7.6.1.  The help for this version doesn't work either, though (typical for Google, really), but this does:

Press on the Search bar, next to the magnifying glass.
Scroll to the bottom of the page.
Click on "Make this map area available offline".

Answer (score 0):

As of [Google Maps v9](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/3273567?hl=en&ref_topic=3273087), Google has changed the method to save offline map:

> 1. Make sure you're connected to the Internet, then open the Google Maps app [image: Google Maps app logo image].
> 2. Search for a place, like "San Francisco."
> 3. Pull up the place info sheet at the bottom of the screen, and touch the menu [image: three vertical dots] in the top right corner.
> 4. Select **Save offline map** to save the selected area of the map. (Sign into your Google Account, if you haven't already.)
> 5. Only what's on the screen will be saved. Adjust the map by moving it and zooming in or out, as needed, then touch **Save**.
> 6. Name the map, and then touch **Save**.
> 7. After a few moments, you'll see a message confirming that the map area has been saved.

Note that typing "OK Map" in Search Bar method is still working, and might be preferable since you don't have to do searching for a particular place first.